# How can I add a business logo in the upper corner of a Power BI template using JSON?

Tags: json, image, powerbi, customization

I am trying to set up a custom Power BI theme using JSON, but I can't get the company logo to do what I want.

**Problem 1**
I saved the JSON script and the .jpg logo in the same folder, and I tried to refer to the logo by using "image" and base64 encoding (online conversion tool):

```
"page": {
    "*": {
        "background": [{
          "image": {
                "name": "high-resolution-color-logo2",
                "scaling": "Normal",
                "url": "<...>"
                }
        }]
}}
```

However, any conversion tool that I use will give me a base64-code that is way too long, and even with changing the max tokenization settings it still won't work. ("<...>" in the code.) Is there any way I can change this, or a different method of adding the logo?
This is the base64 code I get:
[Base64 code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHOkZ.png)

**Problem 2**
I can't seem to figure out how to make the logo smaller and put it in the upper left or right corner. Any thoughts?

I am very new to all this so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am also struggling a little bit with that topic.

But what exactly is the problem, when the image url base 64 gives you is pretty long?

It should not be that big of an issue.

In generell when you want to generate nice templates for Power BI in .json format i can recommend you these two platforms:

- https://themegenerator.point-gmbh.com/de/Home
- https://themes.powerbi.tips/themes/properties

Comment: Thanks David,

The problem with the long base64 code is that it is way too long - can't be copied over completely to JSON and can't be read... It should be much smaller.

Thanks for the links, I'll try them out!